# How do I print a Google Form or convert it to PDF?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace

I've made the perfect Google Form, but I want a paper version.  I need to print a bunch of copies and have people at an event fill them out on paper.  Unfortunately, when I try to simply print the Google Form like it was any other web page, it looks bad and won't really work.  For instance, I have a multiple choice question where the user can only select one answer.  In the printed paper version of the form, you can only see the first choice!  Also, the text fields are too smal

Anyone know of a way to do this or another web app that will help me print this or convert it to a PDF?

Comment: What  browser are you trying to print from, Chrome's print preview is showing my form layout correctly, could you try that? Chrome will also let you print/save to PDF.

Comment: Nah, still collapses any select box into only the first choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got fed up and solved it myself.  I created a tool that allows you to make any Google Form look GREAT on paper.  I decided to charge a little something for a single conversion or a subscription.  I hope it is worth it.  Check out [Google Paper Forms](http://vivwebsolutions.com/tools/google-paper-forms/) and let me know what you think.

Comment: asking for email, drove me away. Seems promising though

Comment: Asking for money to just print a page is quite naughty.

Answer (score 4):

If you go to File > Print you can change the printer to "Save as a PDF". You can do this for any document as well by right clicking, Print, and also changing the printer to "Save as a PDF".

Comment: this will work only if pdf printer driver is installed. pdf printer driver is by default installed with adobe acrobat :)

Comment: Definitely the way to go. You can also edit the resulting page by Inspecting the page and edit/remove anything you don't like. :)

Answer (score 0):

Get a program like "PDF-Creator"; go to the form and press print. Select PDF-Creator as a print medium and save the file as a PDF.